# Selection of important features through cross validation and shape value importance

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, feature-selection, auc

To extract important features for the binary classification problem, recursive feature elimniation was performed based on the importance value of the shap value through nested cv.

The first thing I am curious about here is that when only highly important features remain as shown in the attached figure, does the auc score for train and test decrease, resulting in good generalization, or does the gap decrease because the number of features decreases?

The second is feature selection. I'm not sure at what point I should choose the final number of important features. I used roc auc score, which is a widely used binary classification evaluation metric. Should I simply select the point with the highest auc score for the test set? Or should I select a point with a small gap between train and test? Or should I choose a point that satisfies all these conditions?

The y-axis is the auc score and the x-axis is the number of features removed.

[image]